# How to call methods defined in python in a node written in C++

Tags: rospy, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to call [quat_to_angle()](https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/trac/browser/turtlebot_apps/turtlebot_calibration/src/turtlebot_calibration/calibrate.py#L52) and [normalize_angle()](https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/trac/browser/turtlebot_apps/turtlebot_calibration/src/turtlebot_calibration/calibrate.py#L56) methods defined in [calibrate.py](https://kforge.ros.org/turtlebot/trac/browser/turtlebot_apps/turtlebot_calibration/src/turtlebot_calibration/calibrate.py) in the turtlebot_calibration package in my node written in C++. There is no header file generated of calibrate.py, so is there any way that i can use these methods in my C++ code without rewriting these methods in C++? If not then can u please tell some alternate implementations of these methods already done by someone else?

Thanks

Regards

Usama

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50457/how-to-call-methods-defined-in-python-in-a-node-written-in-c++/) by [usamayaseen](https://answers.ros.org/users/1004/usamayaseen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 69 on 2012-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not without some major overhead compared to the functions.

For C++: `normalize_angle` can be found in the angles package (angles/angles.h) and quat_to_angle can be done using tf functions. For the yaw use `tf::getYaw`. You can provide a `tf::Quaternion` or a `geometry_msgs::Quaternion`.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2